# Archaius Configuration Server setup

Tags: spring-boot, distributed-computing, spring-cloud, apache-commons, netflix-archaius

We are exploring Archaius for our microservices. We want to setup a Configuration Server as microservice and store configuration files of other microservices.

We have other microservices (Springboot based) say 
a) Producer
b) Consumer 
deployed in different environment/vm. We also deploy all these microservices as a cluster (ie., run multiple instances of Producer and Consumer) to support high availability.

Please let us know how to get dynamically changed values in Configuration Server to be available to other microservices (multiple Producer and Consumers).

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify? Archaius and Config Server don't really go together.

Comment: Sorry, we want to have centralized place to store configuration files of various microservices. We are planning to use Archaius as it supports dynamic updation.